# I have create a Net6 Web Program,But it can't debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I had try in my colleague's computer,It works.
My computer had net runtime6.0.20 and SDK 6.0.200
I Can run program in bin file,broswer can open.
Thank you for your answer first

[system.private.corelib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkIwH.png)

The startup hook simple assembly name '\Program Files\dotnet\SDK\6.0.200\DotnetTools\dotnet-watch\6.0.200-rtm.22104.9\tools\net6.0\any\middleware\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.dll' is invalid. It must be a valid assembly name and it may not contain directory separator, space or comma characters and must not end with '.dll'.”

the solution of this problem is to repaire visual studio by Visual studio Installer
[Visual studio Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1qUa.png)

Comment: Looks like a dirty machine problem.  Eliminate the DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS environment variable.  https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/host-startup-hook.md

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely.I had repair it by Visual studio installer,After unistall all net runtime and SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution of this problem is to repair visual studio by Visual studio Installer

[image: Visual studio Installer]